# How to check if a call to Cosmos DB succeeded or failed

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

What would be the best way to check if a call to Cosmos DB succeeded or failed? Should I check the status code in the response or catch an exception or both? Are there any cases where the response status code is not success, but no exception is thrown?

```
ContainerResponse containerResponse = null;
try
{
containerResponse = await cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId).ReadContainerAsync();
if (containerResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Ok)
{
    // the call failed. do something here.
}
}
catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
throw;
}
```

...

Answer (score 2):

In V3 SDK, if you are using the Stream APIs (ReadContainerStreamAsync), then no exceptions will be thrown for failures and you should inspect the status code of the response.

If you use the Typed APIs (ReadContainerAsync), then any failure would throw a CosmosException.

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Exceptions.md#typed-apis

Comment: Thanks for the info and link!

Comment: Please remember to mark the answers for others to benefit

Comment: I'm using 3.13 in a console program and it just dies.  No errors to catch, nothing in the output window.  Was working yesterday and now it's not.  I know it's probably something on my end, but I'm seeing the same behavior with a typed API.